# Beego and Angular 4

Tags: angular, beego

I'm trying to get my head around using beego and Angular4 together. I'm trying to use the angular-cli and generate a new project. Has somebody used the two frameworks together and can share a few insights on setting up their development and production setup/settings etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this question might be a bit old. buit it can be useful to someone else.

Use your Angular 4 as Front end alone, and let your Beego app to act like an api.
create an angular 4 app somewhere in your dev's folders. and create an go app inside your source folder. I have same set up as you trying to do.

and if you want them to act as in the same domain name. you can refer into this nginx server block.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    ## This is your Angular 4 app
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200/;
    }
    ## This is your beego app
    location /api/ {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/;
    }

    access_log  /some/folder/example.com.access.log;
    error_log  /some/folder/example.com.error.log;
}
```